# Azure failing to delete SQL users duing DB deployment

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When deploying .dacpac​ file to Azure SQL database, initially all the users are deleted. In my last deployment the Azure DevOps release pipeline failed to drop the user and thus deployment failed. At this stage, connect permission for all users in SQL database were disabled(red cross near the usernames). I had to add the argument "/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins" run the deployment successfully. But this did not re- enable the connect permission for the users. I have done many SQL deployments in the past without issues using the same release pipeline.

This is the error log

<<

2020-12-08T17:14:50.3332401Z Dropping [ars-brd-qa-sqluser]... 2020-12-08T17:14:50.3919499Z Dropping [adc-brddna-qa]... 2020-12-08T17:14:50.5062700Z An error occurred while the batch was being executed. 2020-12-08T17:14:50.5164191Z Updating database (Failed) 2020-12-08T17:14:50.5346191Z Time elapsed 0:00:40.23 2020-12-08T17:14:50.7677183Z ##[error]*** Could not deploy package. 2020-12-08T17:14:50.7744919Z ##Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15154, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The database principal owns a database scoped credential and cannot be dropped. Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script: DROP USER [adc-brddna-qa];

> > 

Comment: According to your error info  `The database principal owns a database scoped credential and cannot be dropped.`  Suggest you directly use command line ( DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs) against Azure SQL database. 

You could also manually delete the users in Azure side. And then raise a new release in Azure DevOps, check if it works this time. If you still get error, you should check if you lack some permission to run the command or batch script in your release pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to delete the users using command line but I am concerned on how the deployment failed trying to delete the user this time because we have been using the same user to deploy SQL and that user still has admin privileges.

Comment: `I have done many SQL deployments in the past without issues using the same release pipeline.` If this only failed once this time and also work in coming deploys. Thus you may have left a few things inside your databases. If there were mappings between this login and one or more database users (one per database), these users are still there.

For this situation, you may have to manually delete the users.

Comment: We can come to that situation too when we restored one or more databases from a SQL Server instance (source server) to another server (destination server) where all logins mapped to these databases are not created on a destination server, or they are created but with different SID. 

Besides, do you have any PostDeployment script in your database project and kindly check in it  if there was a script that was doing a DELETE.

Comment: We do have a post deployment script which creates users if they are not present in the database. I believe azure devops itselft removes the users in the database before deploying the code.